# Why is a fibonacci function using while loops faster than else: return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)?

Tags: python, recursion, while-loop, fibonacci

So I watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OnXlnd3JB-8
He is giving a 16 year a brief lesson in coding and asks him to make a fibonacci function. At about 10:37 he shows the 16 year old the correct code that tells you the nth number in the fibonacci sequence. Before he revealed this code, I thought that this might be interesting to try myself, considering that I am very much a beginner at coding. I wrote this:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    a = []
    while len(a) == 0:
        a.append(0)
    while len(a) == 1:
        a.append(1)
    while n > len(a):
        a.append(a[len(a) - 1] + a[len(a) - 2])
    return a[n-1]
```

And in the video he writes this:

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n - 2)
```

What I don't understand is why the code that I wrote seems to be so much faster than his in the video. It is my understanding that they do essentially the same thing? But if you go to decently big fibonacci numbers (like the 35th in the sequence) there is a very apparent speed difference. I even went up to 150th number in the sequence for the one I wrote and it still seems to be working in less than a second. So as a newbie, I don't understand exactly how these processes differ and what is making mine faster, so my question is why is it so fast? Thanks

Comment: If you put a ```print()``` statement in the ```fib()``` version, you'll see why it's slower.

Comment: The one you wrote is `O(N)` while the recursive version is `O(N!)`

Comment: See https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node16.html

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Fibonacci_sequence

Comment: @smac89  The recursive code is ```O(2^n)``` and not ```O(n!)```.

Answer (score 0):

The second method uses **Recursion** - *Calling the same function within the function.*

Why it is slower ?

- Recursion (in your code) involves a lot of function calls, which takes time. *Ofcourse, you could cache the results and avoid them.*
- It's Time Complexity is **`O(2^n)`**
- It calculates everything that is already calculated before. *Say n = 5*

```
    fib(5) = fib(4) + fib(3)
    fib(4) = fib(3) + fib(2)
    fib(3) = fib(2) + fib(1)
    fib(2) = fib(1) + fib(0)
```

You can see `f(3), f(2) and f(1)` are calculated again and again.

You don't see the above issues in the first ccode.

For`n = 5`,

- You are just adding the previous two values (`a[4]` and `a[3]`) and storing that in `a[5]`.
- It's Time Complexity is **`O(n)`**.

You can see there are no function calls, no recalculation and That's why it's faster.

Comment: The biggest problem with the second method is redundancies, not function call overhead. You can see the difference at n=40 and by caching the results in a dictionary. I feel like this answer is giving the impression that function call overhead is the primary contributor to runtime.

Comment: I think I have mentioned clearly about the rework done taking n = 5. I cannot take the example of n=50 and show the OP what is happening as there will be a lot of calls.

Comment: Yes, I see that, but from your first point, to me it looks like it's focusing on the fact that it uses recursion rather than the sheer number of recursive calls being made. Here's something else that uses recursion, but doesn't make many function calls: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BCsMgEEXXzilmmSEtOO1OyElKF4nVRghjELMopWe3VuzuD//9N/srr1GupdjZrm56a8MnNvwBGw/JLuGEGh7Oow/LIGRAPbe4zBv2HtQfHCdkUMGjoMSMQbAp60K1cJN7lTXNmQnHHi8EKrl8pM5XDPYUJA@/nrUm6nd/RKV8AQ "Python 3 – Try It Online"). It's really just a gripe of wording though.

Comment: Ok, you're caching the values and so it takes less time. I know that you can use cache and reduce the time. But    I have mentioned my first point based on what the OP has posted and not about Recursion in general. May be I'll have to mention that explicitly. I'll do that. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: No problem. Your answer seems to be the only one that mentions it and gives the correct run time analysis, which is good.

Answer (score -1):

Recursion can be elegant, but it's not the most efficient solution.  There's overhead in making function calls and passing parameters.  Also, your code is not producing the right answers.  You'd need something like this to match their code:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    a = [1,1]
    while n >= len(a):
        a.append(a[-1] + a[-2])
    return a[-1]
```

In the end, there's really no point in keeping the whole list.  All you need are the two most recent entries.

Comment: yeah unless you want the values below n, a simple loop with 2 most recent values would be the best solution

Comment: ?? The problem isn’t just with recursion, it’s about all the duplicated work from the tree-recursive approach, which you don’t even mention.

Comment: The recursive version would be a lot faster if results were cached.